# Using d3.js to sum csv data and publish to html

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to establish a 'pull quote' figure for a dashboard using d3.js. I'm successfully gathering the data, but I'm not sure how to print it out to html. ("#r1b1p1" is the id of the  container). Where am I going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // get filtered data (df)
    d3.csv("/data/cic_data.csv", function (csv) {

    // roll up and group data
    var data = d3.nest()
        .rollup(function(d) { 
        return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.spend; });
        }).entries(csv);

    d3.select("#r1b1p1").append("div").attr("class","pull_fig").html(data);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What is the result you're getting and what result are you expecting?

Comment: I'm getting nothing at the moment. I'm hoping to get a single number (the sum of the 'spend' column) appear in my html.

Comment: Did you verify that the data is loaded correctly? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: The only apparent reasons this would not work is if either there isn't actually a div with `id="#r1b1p1"` in the DOM, or that the div is declared further down below the `<script>` tag (such that it doesn't yet exist when the code runs). Also, if there are more than a single div with that id, it could produce unexpected results. What do you get if you `console.log(d3.select('#r1b1p1').node())`? If it's anything other than the expected DOM node then there you have it....

Comment: I've isolated the code into a new page, with nothing else in it and I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` for the last line within the script tag.